# What's the best way to take care that the footer will always be on the bottom

Tags: html, css, styles, footer

I have this site : http://test.tamarawobben.nl

What's the best way to achieve that the footer will always be on the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Have a look at this link. http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and mark it as accepted if it work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS for the footer

```
footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

Full article on this : [How to keep footers at the bottom of the page](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "always on the bottom". There are two type of footers that are "always on the bottom": Fixed and sticky.

A fixed footer is always on the bottom *of the browser window*, where as a sticky footer is always on the bottom *of the page content or the browser, whichever is lower*.

For the sticky footer, you can check out the code [on this page](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/). For a fixed footer, you just want to give it the following properties:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial on how to do this - http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page.

Should get you what you're looking for.